# What does "polyadic" mean in the context of functional programming and type systems?

Tags: terminology, functional-programming, type-systems, polymorphism

And how does it (or does not) correspond to "polymorphic"? Occasionally I see this notion like in: [Implement and represent polyadic operations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4599587/1333025). I checked [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/polyadic) but it only gives a general meaning, not specific to functional programming.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**It's really simple to understand.**

- A function that takes zero arguments is called *niladic* function.
- A function that takes one argument only is called *monadic* function.
- A function that takes two arguments is called *dyadic* function.
- A function that takes three arguments it called *triadic* function.
- A function that takes multiple arguments is called *polyadic* function.
- A function that takes a variable number of arguments is called [*variadic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) function.

How does this relate to polymorphy? Imho it does not relate to polymorphy at all. I think often times polyadic and variadic are substitutable. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) for further information.

**How does this relate to functional programming?**

I think the following wikipedia quote sais it all:

> There are many mathematical and logical operations that come across naturally as variadic functions.
>   For instance, the summing of numbers or the concatenation of strings
>   or other sequences are operations that can logically apply to any
>   number of operands.

Comment: How is that different from _unary_, _binary_, _ternary_ etc.function? Just a note, in the context of functional programming, a _monadic function_ could also mean something very different (a function that works with a monad).

Comment: It is not different from unary, binary, ternary. It's very much the same. There can be differences depending on the language used. An unary operator can also be called monadic operator.

Comment: What it the difference between a variadic function and a function that takes one argument of type list?

Comment: @Giorgio: The signature and the type of the function. func(List) != func(arg1, arg2... arg_n); This is merely in the typesystem. As an anlogy, think about recursive functions that can always be implemented as stack-based iterative functions.

Comment: @Falcon: I wonder (1) how the possibility of using a variadic function adds expressive power to a language if the same result can be achieved using lists, and (2) how the concept of variadic functions interacts with currying.

Comment: @Giorgio: (1) Take a look at c's sprintf or printf functions; (2) Imho there's no impact on currying. Variadic functions can be curryed like any other function. But I am really not sure about it.

Comment: @Falcon Look at Haskell's `Text.Printf` for a curried variadic function.